# Is there a way to identify which target is being compiled in a build.rs file?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

My `cargo.toml` is:

```
bin = [
    { name = "first", path = "bin/first.rs" },
    { name = "second", path = "bin/second.rs" },
]
[lib]
name = "some_lib"
crate-type = [
    "cdylib",
    "rlib",
]

[target."cfg(windows)".build-dependencies]
winresource = "0.1"
```

When compiled, two executables are generated: `first.exe` and `second.exe`. In order to have custom icons for the executables on windows, I use the following `build.rs` script:

```
use std::io;
#[cfg(windows)] use winresource::WindowsResource;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=build.rs");
    #[cfg(windows)] {
        WindowsResource::new()
            // This path can be absolute, or relative to your crate root.
            .set_icon("icon_for_first.ico")
            .compile()?;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

This applies the resource to **every** executable, rather than just `first.exe`. Is there a way to check the target that is being compiled?

Comment: No there isn't. Note that `build.rs` is only run _once_ even if cargo then builds multiple executables. What you need is some way to have multiple `WindowsResource`s and tell them to which executable they should apply, but AFICS that's not possible with v0.1.15. You can [file an enhancement request](https://github.com/BenjaminRi/winresource/issues/new) and in the meantime you will need to use separate crates for your executables.

Comment: Side notes: [the relevant docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#life-cycle-of-a-build-script) (i.e. once per package, not once per bin), and: For now, you can create a workspace with two separate packages (i.e. two separate `Cargo.toml`s  and `build.rs`.)